# Is this usage wrong? A: "What do you want to do in your free time?" B: "I would like to see my parents in my free time"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Longman [Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/would) defines *would* as,

> **6.** "***would like***" is used to say that someone wants something or
> wants to do something
>
> *My parents would like to meet you.*

But this English teacher said in a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trKQm1ZXmQ0)

"***would like***" should be used in specific situation (right-now need).

So, I would say "***would like***" is a formal form of "**want**" but only for "**wanting something in a specific situation**"

See **scenario 1**,

> A: *What do you want to do in your free time?* (**general "want"**)
>
> B: *I would like to see my parents in my free time.*
> (this sentence sounds very wrong to me though I am not a native speaker)

B needs to say: *I want to see my parents in my free time.*

See **scenario 2**,

> A: *What do you want to do now?* (**specific "want"**, a "**want it right now**")
>
> B: *I would like to see my parents right now.* (this sentence is fine & sounds more formal than "*I want to see...*")

So, I would like to ask users, if the following usage is wrong.

> A: *What do you want to do in your free time?*
>
> B: *I **would like** to see my parents in my free time*

Comment: Like I said "**would like**" should be used for "**want**" in specific situations not for "**want**" in general situations

Comment: There _is_ a problem, but it's not with the choice of 'would like'. 'I would like to see more of my parents in my free time' is totally acceptable / idiomatic. 'I would like to meet my parents in my free time' (like 'I want to meet my parents in my free time), although not strictly wrong, sounds incongruously punctive, like 'I would like to watch "Batman Begins" in my free time.' ['Free time' is usually used for 'leisure time' rather than 'break'.](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22free+time%22+meaning&*)

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked before, but the question indicated by Josh does not answer this one. As @EdwinAshworth points out,  this is a question about appropriacy, not grammar as such.

Comment: "The accepted answer addresses  the "appropriacy"  issue.

Comment: This question is completely different from others'. Not a duplicate one.

Comment: @Josh I humbly disagree. The problem lies with "free time" not with "want" or "would like". The OP's sentence is grammatical, but not idiomatic sounding. "**I'd like to see my parents more often**, *but I don't have enough free time*" fits. The one cited by the OP doesn't.

Comment: I changed all "meet" to "see", how are you going to answer it?

Comment: Why noone answers the general & specific aspects addressed in the questions? So you mean "would like" can be used for general situations?

Comment: @tom you've corrected the sentence by yourself, without knowing, I offered a better solution in my example sentence because  "**Seeing your parents**" is more natural sounding than "**meeting your parents**". This question now becomes POB, (IMO) after your edit.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, what about the "general & specific meaning aspects" of the sentences?

Comment: Would like can express a desire or a wish. E.g. "I would like to see my parents more often, but I can't." is perfectly correct and idiomatic. The older question linked by Josh seems to answer your question much better now. amazing what changing one word can do. @Josh  I would like to retract my reopen vote, but I can't unfortunately.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, then your "**would like**" is different from my "**would-like**". My one is about "**wants something or wants to do something**" as "**showed in the dictionary**", not a "**wish**"

Comment: @Josh if I say I can't, it's because I've tried. The time limit has probably expired, or maybe reopen votes cannot be retracted. I would retract it now, if I could.

Comment: @Tom The verb *want* is just a stronger form for "*desire*"  and an acceptable synonym for *wish*. There are 2 reopen votes, if users agree that the question should be reopen, they will cast their vote in favour, if they don't it means they agree with Josh (and now myself).

Comment: Concentrating on your other examples (rather than the one in the title), (2) _My parents would like to meet you._ is far less demanding/threatening,  more hedged, than _My parents want to meet you_. // (3A) _What do you want to do now?_ could equally well be _What would you like to do now?_ (3B) _I would like to see my parents right now._ is the natural choice; _I want to see my parents now._ sounds demanding/urgent. //// There may be specificity issues, but I'd say that here, at least, the tone of the statements is the important factor.